# Not Able to Query Multiple Times from Multiple Common Table Expressions (WITH)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I was doing some querying today in T-SQL, SQL-Server-2008 and stumbled upon something weird that I didn't understand.  Using the query windows, I am trying to query from two common table expressions like so (I stripped out a lot of code to make it more obvious what I was doing):

```
;WITH temp1 AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Log)
, temp2 AS (SELECT  * FROM dbo.SignalCodeItems300_tbl)

SELECT * FROM temp1
SELECT * FROM temp2
```

However, only one of the select statements will run, the FIRST one.  Regardless of which is which, only the first runs.  I assume this is some sort of syntax thing that I'm missing maybe?  I get the error "Invalid object name 'temp2'".

Could someone shed some light on this problem?  Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this works as it should.  A CTE (Common Table Expression) is only available for the first statement after the definition.  So in other words, after `select * from temp1`, they both become unavailable.

The fix would be this:

```
;WITH temp1 AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Log)
SELECT * FROM temp1

;WITH temp2 AS (SELECT  * FROM dbo.SignalCodeItems300_tbl)
SELECT * FROM temp2
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Especially:

```
Multiple CTE query definitions can be defined in a nonrecursive CTE. 
The definitions must be combined by one of these set operators:
UNION ALL, UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT.
```

You cannot mix and match two different schemas though, as this essentially runs as one query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a view or a user-defined, table-valued function to house your query if you don't want to repeat it explicitly.